# Google Login is not working on Release builds

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I am working on an app where i need to authenticate my users using Google and Facebook login, On Debug build both of them are working completely fine, but when i uploaded it on playstore both of them stopped working, so for Facebook login all i need to do is to make the project public inside Facebook developers console. But Google login is not working.

I am getting this response code inside API exception block "10:", i am not able to fix this issue as i am not getting any clue where i am doing wrong, even there is no log so that i can go through that also to find the culprit.

This is the code i am using

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        signIn();
    }
});


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        Uri googleUserPicUrl = null;
        googleUserName = account.getDisplayName();
        googleUserEmail = account.getEmail();
        googleUserPicUrl = account.getPhotoUrl();
        googleUserId = account.getId();
        if (googleUserPicUrl != null) {
            googleUserPic = googleUserPicUrl.toString();
        } else {
            googleUserPic = null;
        }
        storeUserData("google");
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        System.out.println("API EXCEPTION GOOGLE : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is not the uploaded app but the release variant you are running on your device? is minify enabled?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack minify is disabled for release build type

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is that the oauth client is using a debug key  for the project.  If it was not signed it would not let you upload and it is. Thats only a guess...

Comment: I have uploaded the release SHA1 in my Firebase project and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You must Sign your app and add Signing configs to gradle.
Look [here](https://coderwall.com/p/zrdsmq/signing-configs-with-gradle-android) for example, and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)